# Can I open a PHAsset directly in Photos app?

Tags: objective-c, ios13, photosframework

In my app I just want to show all photos taken within a specific date range in a collection view. If a user clicks a picture I would love if it directly opens the picture/movie in the photos app. Is that possible?

Comment: I want to do this too! I can do it in AppleScript: `tell application "Photos" to spotlight media item id "5F6A1817-012C-4ED7-B55D-8894A842C099/L0/001"` and I can open the Photos app with the `photos://` URL scheme, but I can't work out how to pick an asset with the URL scheme approach. :-/